# Spring property value from console

Tags: java, spring

I am working on a spring application and i need to provide the values of properties at run time.

**XML:**

```
<bean id="circle" class="test.hhh.org.Circle">
    <property name="radius" value="NEED DYNAMIC VALUE HERE"/>
</bean>
```

So in main class:

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = sc.nextInt(); //dynamic value 
    }
 }
```

`num` should be value of the radius. How can I configure this value in Spring?  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

For a Spring application I would recommend a configuration file or an environment variable.

Environment variable reading in Java:

```
System.getenv("RADIUS")
```

Property file reading in spring:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:foo.properties")
public class PropertiesWithJavaConfig {

@Value( "${radius.value}" )
private int radius;

 @Bean
 public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
   propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
   return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
  }
}
```

The foo.properties file should be under your resources directory.

```
./src/main/java/resources/foo.properties
```

And it's content should be:

```
radius.value=11
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But still the value 11 is static right? how can we assign a value on runtime? Any value?

Comment: So your question if about, you want to accept user input?
Or some form of dynamic settings?

1. You could enhance the second version with the property file so there could be periodic checks on the file, that way you could change it dynamically.

2. Or use a controller with Spring to accept user input, but that's on a Http level of course.

If you just want to read from console, I'm not sure spring supports this. If you want to have user input from command line, I don't see the point of using Spring.